# How to add a bit sequence to the end of another sequence?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, binary-data

I have an bit sequence that is created using memset, I want to add the return of a function to the first sequence.

```
U16 *pointer_p = allocmem(); // 500 bytes
memset (&pointer_p, 0, size); // size = 497 bytes
U32 A = function(); //3 byte return value
```

how to append the return from the function at the end of data created, would the line of code below work?

```
pointer_p = (*pointer_p<<24)| A ;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Should the data be inserted big- or little-endian? What is your processor, big- or little-endian?

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
memset (&pointer_p, 0, size); // size = 497 bytes
```

to

```
memset (pointer_p, 0, size); // size = 497 bytes
```

Then, assuming little endian

```
((char *)pointer_p)[497] = A & 0xFFu;
((char *)pointer_p)[498] = (A >> 8) & 0xFFu;
((char *)pointer_p)[499] = (A >> 16) & 0xFFu;
```

For big endian just change the indices

```
((char *)pointer_p)[499] = A & 0xFFu;
((char *)pointer_p)[498] = (A >> 8) & 0xFFu;
((char *)pointer_p)[497] = (A >> 16) & 0xFFu;
```

It's not clear how this is supposed to work with your `U16` elements.